# will_paginate-3.0.pre2 gem not compatible with Rails 3, alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Are there effective gem alternatives for the gem will_paginate-3.0.pre2?

will_paginate-3.0.pre2 is not supported by our version of Rails which is 3.1.3?

We are continually working on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, creating an application from scratch using this tutorial as a guideline, and it uses the above gem in the tutorial. Any chance we could insert one of these alternative gems compatible with Rails 3.1.3 where the will_paginate gem would have been inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). Plus also check out [Ryan Bate's Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) on it too.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest version. Update your gem file then "bundle install" and continue with the tutorial.
So your gem file will now have `gem 'will_paginate'` instead of `'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using version 3.0.2 of will_paginate - add this to your gemfile

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.2"
```

Comment: The problem is that in the tutorial Posts.all returns an array and not an ActiveRecord collection. Supposedly requiring 'will_paginate/array' in the controller will make it work, but I haven't been able to do so.

Comment: This is the paginated version of Posts.all - @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page]), https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki